# fontDialog1 изменение шрифта всей формы C#

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Код открытия `Fontdialog1` :

```
DialogResult result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Как сделать, чтобы в выборе шрифта в `FontDialog1` у всей формы поменялся шрифт на выбранный?

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать рекурсивный цикл по контролам, и у всех менять цвет.

```
void ChangeFont(Control ctrl, Font font)
{
  ctrl.Font = font;

  foreach (Control inner in ctrl.Controls)
    ChangeFont(inner, font);
}
```

После выбора цвета вызвать этот метод, передав ему форму и выбранный цвет.

Comment: Modus, Я проверил ваш ответ, НО выдает огромное кол-во ошибок! Я думаю ваш код/цикл, НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ! Может конечно и на моем MSV C# и не работает, но все равно!...

Comment: Давайте конкретно, что не так. Этот цикл - пример того, как обойти все контролы на форме. Дальше надо смотреть конкретно, что не получается, и вставлять условия в зависимости от того, что именно создаёт проблемы.